# How to access a JavaScript variable which is included in a html file and this file is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file called index.html. There is a div object in this html and in this div we load another html call abc.html dynamically using object tag. My question is how can i access a variable of abc.html from index.html.

Comment: Do you have an example we can look at? What have you tried? What reasearch have you already done on your own on this?

Comment: If whatever you use to "load" abc.html into the DIV also process the javascript on abc.html then it should just be available. But as there is many way and libraries that can be use to load external files into an element it's hard to provide much more useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, assuming you are using Ajax to load abc.html into a `<div>` element in index.html.

> Now once abc.html is loaded into index.html's div, both abc.html and
>   index.html become a singular entity.

so lets say you had the following on abc.html

```
var message = "Annoying message";
```

and this function on index.html

```
function annoyingAlert() {
    alert(message);
}
```

and you call the "annoyingAlert" method in the Ajax's onLoadComplete event in your index.html, it should pop up your annoying message you originally had on abc.html

*You are just working with a single page, in which some content is loaded dynamically.*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. We had already tried doing this but no success :( . This is how we are including abc.html in a div of index.html    lessonStorage.innerHTML = '<object id="foo" name="foo" type="text/html" data="' + destUrlPath + '"><\/object>';

Comment: where lessonStorage is a div and the value of destUrlPath is abc.html